# How to make 2 divs the same height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get 2 divs that do not have a common parent div to be the height of the larger div. (using `display: flex`).

As shown in the above code, I would like `<child-div1>` and `<child-div2>` to have the same height. Currently, I have `display: flex` on the `<parent-div>` which successfully makes `<middle-div1>` and `<middle-div2>` to have the same height. However, I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that `<child-div1>` and `<child-div2>` have the same height.

```html
<parent-div style="display: flex">
    <middle-div1>
        <child-div1></child-div1>
    </middle-div1>
    <middle-div2>
        <child-div2></child-div2>
    </middle-div2>
</parent-div>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, `height: inherit` for child-div1 and child-div2 will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to figure it out you could right click in the page, then select inspect element, and you going to see a window like this:

[image]

by clicking the most left icon and hovering over the two divs, you are going to see the exact width x height

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` to the `<middle-div>` flex items.

This will automatically apply `align-items: stretch` to the `<child-div>` children. (Just note that a `height` rule will override `align-items: stretch`.)

Answer (score 0):

With that layout, you can set both children to have `height: inherit;` it's inheriting the height from the tallest part of the container. So for example, if you have an image on one side that is 400 px tall, that stretches the container, therefore, allowing the other child to grow in height also.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.one, .two {
  height: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

.one {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.two {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one">1<br><img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff&text=test"></div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add `height:100%;` to `child-div1` and `child-div2`

```
<parent-div style = "display: flex">
    <middle-div1>
        <child-div1 style="height: 100%;"></child-div1>
   </middle-div1>
    <middle-div2>
        <child-div2 style="height: 100%;"></child-div2>
    </middle-div2>
</parent-div>
```